# Lamson for clojure?

Tags: clojure, jvm, lamson

Are there any java or clojure mail libraries out there that do what lamson does? In particular, the mail routing features of lamson are very cool http://verpa.wordpress.com/2010/11/13/making-your-webapp-react-to-emails-with-lamson-pt-2/ are there any thing like that for the jvm?

Comment: Do you want it specifically for Clojure or for the jvm so Clojure could access it?

Comment: It could be for either, as long as Clojure can access the libraries... I can write a wrapper for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) is rather sophisticated and can send mail via STMP and receive using POP3 and IMAP. You can build a layer to route mails yourself. Maybe [Apache JAMES](http://james.apache.org/) is useful for you too.

Comment: apache james is pretty cool. the mailets toolkit does a similar job to lamson